# get error when showing dojo simple dialog

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I've written a on click function to show a simple dojo dialog, but instead it shows

> NO_FAST_DRAW = false

This actually works in Nexus 4, 5 and other devices - but not in Samsung Galaxy S2.

```
 on(dojo.byId("send_email"), "click", function() 
            {
                    console.log("emailClicked1");
                    dijit.registry.byId("emailDialog").show();
                    dojo.byId("emailsText").value="";
                    dojo.byId("dialogFlag").value="emailDialog";
                    console.log("emailClicked2");
            });
```

I can see the console email Clicked1 and 2 but not able to see the dialog as well in UI.

```
<div id="emailDialog" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SimpleDialog">
        <form id="emailDialogForm">
            <div id="emailDialogText">
                <p class="blue_text" style="text-align: left;">To:</p>
                <input id="emailsText" type="email"
                    style="line-height: 2em; width: 95%; margin: 3px; border: none; padding: 2px; font-size: 0.65em;"
                    placeholder="Enter email ID (Separate multiple IDs by ,)" />
            </div>
            <div class="button_grid">
                <input type="submit" id="submitEmail" value="Send" /> <input
                    type="button" id="cancelEmail" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the onclick function handler, "show()" action of dialog is asynchronous. So, any code that deals with the content of the dialog, needs to be done only after the show() is completed. i.e, the deferred action needs to be handled.

```
console.log("emailClicked1");
var def = dijit.registry.byId("emailDialog").show();
if(def) {
 def.then(function(success) {
   dojo.byId("emailsText").value="";
 });
}
dojo.byId("dialogFlag").value="emailDialog";
console.log("emailClicked2");
```